# The usage of "individual"

Tags: word-usage

> Another side-effect of performing a single act of euthanasia is that
> it might make it easier for unscrupulous doctors to kill patients
> under the guise of it being the wishes of the patient. Opponents of
> all euthanasia often point out that Hitler’s extermination techniques
> were first tried out on victims of an involuntary euthanasia
> programme. Perhaps every **individual** act of voluntary euthanasia
> makes it easier for someone to bring in a policy of involuntary
> euthanasia.

Philosohy: The Basics

I don't know the usage of "individual" before "act of voluntary euthanasia". Is it redundant?

Answer (score 1):

It's redundant in terms of the final meaning of the sentence, but it has an impact on how the reader thinks about the meaning.

Yes, `...every individual act...` means the same as `...every single act...` or just `...every act...`.

At the same time, the word "individual" in your example focuses the reader on the the possibility that each act of euthanasia moves society closer to creating official policy on euthanasia. This is editorializing -- making the text partial to one particular opinion.